# How can I set value to CfnWebACL.DefaultActionProperty.Allow property in WAFv2 from AWS CDK and .NET core

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-waf

I'm trying to create WAFv2 WebAcl service using AWS CDK. My programming language is C# (.NET Core). I'm not able to figure out how to set value of CfnWebACL.DefaultActionProperty.Allow or CfnWebACL.DefaultActionProperty.Block property as it is an object type and any value I assign to it result in runtime error.

Comment: I have a typescript example, would you like me to post it? it might be helpful

Comment: Please it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 new CfnWebACL(this, "webacl", new CfnWebACLProps
{
            DefaultAction = new CfnWebACL.DefaultActionProperty
            {
                Allow = new CfnWebACL.RuleActionProperty() { Allow = true }
            },
            ...
});
```

This model type seems to work for me ^

Comment: Could you check what is wrong with this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654040/testwebacl-error-reason-your-statement-has-multiple-values-set-for-a-field-that

Answer (score 0):

For those using Java as a language for CDK script:

```
`CfnWebACL.DefaultActionProperty.builder()
                .allow(CfnWebACL.RuleActionProperty.builder().allow(TRUE).build())
                .build();`
```

Answer (score 0):

and for the pythoneers amongst us:

```
some_webacl = CfnWebACL(
    self,
    'some_webacl',
    default_action=CfnWebACL.DefaultActionProperty(block={}),
    scope='REGIONAL',
    visibility_config=CfnWebACL.VisibilityConfigProperty(
        cloud_watch_metrics_enabled=True,
        metric_name=NAME_PREFIX + 'some_webacl',
        sampled_requests_enabled=True
    ),
    description=NAME_PREFIX + 'some_webacl',
    rules=[]
)
```